# Is there a name for this property of a binary relation? $\forall x\forall y(x\mathsf{R}y\to\exists z(x\mathsf{R}z\land y\mathsf{R}z)))$

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, relations, modal-logic

Consider a binary relation $\mathsf{R}$ such that $x\mathsf{R}y$ is the case only if there is some $z$ such that both $x\mathsf{R}z$ and $y\mathsf{R}z$ are the case.
Is there a well-known name for the property enjoyed by this relation?  And are there natural examples in mathematics (or in [ARS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_rewriting_system)) of relations characterized by this property?

In normal modal logic, the above property characterizes frames axiomatized by the schema $\lozenge\square\alpha\to\lozenge\alpha$ (or, dually, by $\square\alpha\to\square\lozenge\alpha$).  It amounts to a stronger version of the [Church-Rosser property](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Church-RosserProperty.html), according to which $x\mathsf{R}y$ and $y\mathsf{R}x$ are *simultaneously* the case only if there is a $z$ such that both $x\mathsf{R}z$ and $y\mathsf{R}z$ are the case.  I have however been unable to determine so far whether there is an established name for the above mentioned property in the literature.

(This is [cross-posted](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/20635/16763) with TCS.SE, where the question received a couple of comments but no answers were posted in the first few days.)

Comment: If you had "if and only if" in the definition instead of just "only if" then you could call such a relation a _symmetric idempotent_ (with respect to relational composition). But as it stands I can't immediately think of a suitable name.

Comment: can you add all relations ( is it transitive and or serial) maybe the combination of relations has a name, as afar as i can see refexive includes yor relation and it is a bit a combination of serial and connective  , in G' notation it is an G(0,1,1,1) but this one doesn't has a name

Comment: @Willemien Indeed, from the comments I received so far it seems that the axiom G(0,1,1,1) ---or, equivalently, G(1,1,0,1)--- has not been baptized, or even studied for its own sake.  It does seem to correspond, anyway, to a qualified version of the notion of [joinability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_rewriting_system#Joinability_and_the_Church.E2.80.93Rosser_property), in ARS, where one demands $x\mathsf{R}y$ as a necessary condition for $x\downarrow y$.

Comment: Abstract rewriting is a different logic branch, (I think it belongs to combinatory logic or Lamda calculus, branches I am not familiar with. I am not sure if it is possible to put Abstract rewriting in a  one-to-one relation with modal logc, I can only advice you to be very careful here, take nothing for obvious. (the arrow with star looks very transitive but then is []p -> [][]p an axiom? The same for []p -> p (reflexivity) is it vacously true or false? and most important: Is |-p => |-[]p (rule of nesecitation, needed for normal modal logics) valid? all questions I don't know the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Had a look around and Hughes "introduction to model logic" and Boolos" The logic of provability" call it CONVERGENT, athough Hughes only calls <>[]p -> []<>p convergent Boolos is more flexibel: 
see Boolos page 88

Comment: In the study of abstract rewriting systems, such _diamond property_ is a particular case of the notion of [confluence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluence_%28abstract_rewriting%29).  You get [convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_%28logic%29) if you add _termination_ to confluence.